# Issue with decoding json, "The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format."

Tags: json, swift

New to Swift and coding in general. I can't seem to find what is wrong with my json / struct.

I am only including a small part of my json here.

```
[
    {
    
    "name": "pollock",
    "price": 749.99,
    "avaliableStock": [
        {
        "size": "xs",
        "stock": 0
        },
        {
        "size": "s",
        "stock": 4
        },
        {
            "size": "m",
            "stock": 0
        },
        {
            "size": "l",
            "stock": 3
        },
        {
            "size": "xl",
            "stock": 2
        }
    ],
    "gender": "men",
    "category": "summer",
    "mainImage": "pollockMain",
    "sideImage": "pollockSide1",
    "sideImage2": "pollockSide2",
    "backImage": "pollockBack"

    }
    
]
```

My struct for the json:

```
struct Product: Identifiable, Decodable {
    
    var id: UUID?
    var name: String
    var price: Double
    var avaliableStock: AvaliableStock
    var gender: String
    var category: String
    var mainImage: String
    var sideImage: String
    var sideImage2: String
    var backImage: String
    
    
}

struct AvaliableStock: Identifiable, Decodable {
    
    var id: UUID?
    var size: String
    var stock: Int
    
}
```

and finally my json decoder:

```
//
//  dataServices.swift
//  tgkb
//
//  Created by Jude Comninos on 2023/01/11.
//

import Foundation

class DataService {
    
    static func getLocalData() -> [Product] {
        
        let pathString = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "data", ofType: "json")
        guard pathString != nil else {
            return [Product]()
        }
        
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: pathString!)
        
        do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
            
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            
             do {
                let productData = try decoder.decode([Product].self, from: data)
                
                for var p in productData {
                    p.id = UUID()
                }
                for var s in productData {
                    s.avaliableStock.id = UUID()
                }
                return productData
            }
            catch {
                print("DEBUG: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
        catch {
            print("DEBUG: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            
        }
        return [Product]()
    }
    
}
```

I have checked all the variables, I think they are all correct and correspond with each other. I am getting the following error: DEBUG: The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.

Thank you.

Comment: Replace `print("DEBUG: \(error.localizedDescription)")` with `print("DEBUG: ", error)`. It will show you a detailed error message. At first glance I see that `avaliableStock` is an array.

Comment: `print("DEBUG: \(error.localizedDescription)")` -> `print("DEBUG: \(error)")` and show the error

Comment: Unrelated, but it be better to write `guard let pathString = Bundle... else { return [Product]() }`

Comment: DEBUG: typeMismatch(Swift.Dictionary<Swift.String, Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [_JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0), CodingKeys(stringValue: "avaliableStock", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found an array instead.", underlyingError: nil))

Comment: `var avaliableStock: AvaliableStock` -> `var avaliableStock: [AvaliableStock]`